# Inflections of the adverb 'well' (some senses are invariable)

Tags: adverbs, comparative, dictionaries

> Inflections of the adverb '**[well](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00282619)**' (*Some senses are invariable*)
>
> *Better* adv comparative ; *best* adv superlative
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/well

What does the dict. refer to by "*Some senses are invariable*"?

Comment: I think the real issue here is not what the correct usage is but whether the dictionary explains itself clearly. I've never used that dictionary before, and I found the description baffling.

Comment: wordreference is not a real dictionary. Just a mismosh of stuff,

Answer (score 1):

Some of the usages listed, such as *shake the bottle well*, cannot be changed to *better* or *best.* 'Shake it well' means 'shake it until any sediment at the bottom is mixed in' - we might say "Shake it a bit more", but not "Shake it better".

Comment: ["**Completely** and properly", as in _Add the lemon juice and mix well._](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/well_1?q=well) However,  "Occasional  objections to modifying  **complete** with qualifiers like _almost, more, most, nearly, quite_, because they suggest that it is relative rather than absolute, but such uses are fully standard and occur regularly in all varieties of spoken and written English."  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/complete

Comment: If you are implying that you don't like my example, then "I couldn't very well refuse" is another case where _well_ is invariable.